# struct.pack shows shifted data

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib, struct.pack

I am trying to use struct.pack to pack a hash disgest, but not getting the expected result.

This is how I am packing the data:

```
hash = hashlib.sha256(input).digest()
print('hash = ', hash.hex())
packed = struct.pack('!32p', hash)
print('packed = ', packed.hex())
```

Here is an example result:
hash = b5dbdb2b0a7d762fc7e429062d64b711d240e8f95f1c59fc28c28ac6677ffeaf

packed = 1fb5dbdb2b0a7d762fc7e429062d64b711d240e8f95f1c59fc28c28ac6677ffe

The bytes appear to be shifted, and "1f" has been added. Is this a result of an incorrect format specifier?

EDIT: I believe this first byte is the length of the data, because I am using 'p'. Is there any way to avoid this? I don't want to include this in my packed data

Answer (score 0):

The `'p'` format character encodes a “Pascal string”  which includes the string's length at the beginning. This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters). If you don't want that use `'s'` format to get just the bytes themselves instead:

```
packed = struct.pack('!32s', hash)
print('packed =', packed.hex())
```

Output:

```
packed = b5dbdb2b0a7d762fc7e429062d64b711d240e8f95f1c59fc28c28ac6677ffeaf
```